# Why I cannot align sub-figures and sub-captions in center?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfig

I have two sub-figures and sub-captions, which are above each other. I cannot align them in the center, and I cannot increase the space between them.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.15\textheight}  
        \centering
        \includegraphics{Fig2a.JPG}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.15\textheight}
        \centering  
        \includegraphics{Fig2b.JPG}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption { (a) Something , and (b)another thing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Could you please help me. Thank you.

Comment: In TeX a blank line means a paragraph break, so you are inserting a paragraph break between your pictures. Also, each `\caption` inside the `subfigure` is mean to be used to label each of the subfigures.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I meant to put a break between them because I needed them above each other, not side by side.

Comment: Ooh, sorry, I fixed my answer :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Please, I have another question if you don't mind. So, I have two pictures, this time side by side, but the have different height. How can I align them based on the bottom?  Thanks in advance

Comment: It's usually not good practice in this site to ask questions in the comments, it's best if you ask a different question. But just this once ;). I don't know what the `[normal]` option to `subfigure` does, but you can use `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}` to align them at the `b`ottom. The `subfigure` environment is a wrapper around LaTeX's `minipage` environment. If you look up on how to align minipages, the same will apply to subfigures ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Something}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Another thing}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{General description of things}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When you say `\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textheight}` you are creating a box with *width* of `0.15\textheight`, which doesn't make much sense. I changed to `0.45\textwidth`, but you can change as you want.

Furthermore, the size of the box you created does not imply that the figure will be that size. You have to pass the size of the figure to `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

this will make the picture have a width equals `\textwidth` which, inside the box you created with `subfigure` is `0.45\textwidth`.

Also, the caption inside the `subfigure` will automatically put the caption below the subfigure.

And the `\centering` has to go outside the `subfigures`, because you want them to be centered in respect to the whole `figure`. You would need the `\centering` inside the `subfigure` only if the width of the width of the `\includegraphics` were less than `\textwidth`.

I also inserted a `\bigskip` between the subfigures to make some vertical space between them.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. I am so thankful for your help.